# Query select record value as % of total records value for each group by value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like the one below

```
product....group....sales
1..........A........1000
2..........A........2000
3..........B........3000
```

I would like to calculate the % of each group in total sales

```
A....50%
B....50%
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select groupid, sum(sales),
       100 * sum(sales) / (select sum(sales) from table)
from table
group by groupid;
```

If `sales` is an integer, you may need to convert it to a floating point representation, if you want more precision.